# Filehelpers only reads one line of data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filehelpers

I wrote a code using filehelpers to read in a csv file and then output to console just the two columns that I want the value of. The problem is that it only prints out one row's worth of data. How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;


namespace prototype_using_filehelpers
{
    [DelimitedRecord("|")]
    [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
    [IgnoreFirst()]
    [IgnoreLast(2)]
    public class ManagerReportNames
    {    
        public int? MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
        public int? MASTER_VALUE;
        public string RESORT;
        public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
        public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
        public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
        public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
        public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
        public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
        public string SUB_GRP_1;
        public string DESCRIPTION;
        public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
        public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
        public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
        public int? HEADING_1;
        [FieldOptional]
        public string HEADING_2;
        [FieldOptional]
        [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
        public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
        [FieldOptional]
        public decimal? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
    }

    class ManagerReport
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
            var records = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\bt\Documents\report.txt") as ManagerReportNames[];
            
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (record.RESORT);
                Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                Console.ReadLine();                 
            }              
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

TL
64.68

However, The file has well over 50 rows. How do i get them all to display

I tried writing it another way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using FileHelpers;
namespace prototype_3
{
    class Program
    {

        [DelimitedRecord("|")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
        [IgnoreFirst()]
        [IgnoreLast(2)]
        public class ManagerReportNames
        {
            public int MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
            public int? MASTER_VALUE;
            public string RESORT;
            public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
            public int LAST_YEAR_01;
            public int SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
            public string SUB_GRP_1;
            public string DESCRIPTION;
            public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
            public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
            public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
            public int? HEADING_1;
            [FieldOptional]
            public string HEADING_2;
            [FieldOptional]
            [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
            public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
            [FieldOptional]
            public decimal? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;
        }    

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\bt\Documents", @"C:\Users\bt\Documents\Complete");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string copyPath, string destinationPath)
        {
            // first check if path exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(copyPath))
                // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
                return;

            var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(copyPath);
            // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
            var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the file
                var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];
                string lines = csvFile.FullName;

                // read the csv file line by line
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
                var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ManagerReportNames[];

                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                }

                // move the files over to another place
                var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                }
                csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because I want to start integrating the use of looping through multiple files and then moving them to a separate folder. I've been testing it using only one file and the moving of the file works. I am also getting more than one row. However, the outputted rows begin half-way through the file. What is wrong with my code that is causing these 2 issues.

Comment: I tested both blocks of code and they seem to work with a sample data file I created. They both return multiple entries (you need to hit return after each result in the first example as you're using `Console.ReadLine()`). And they both read from the start of the file. Would you be able to add a few lines from the data file to the question?

Comment: Do you realise the code you took down for privacy reasons is still visible in the edit history?

Comment: it wouldn't let me delete it completely. It's not a huge deal. If someone really wanted to look at the code and will go through the edits it's fine but I just wanted it not obviously out in the open

Comment: Vandalizing your post in no way protects your privacy. If you want your post gone, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested with your data sample, the first code sample works but expects you to hit ENTER between each record. If you change:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine (record.RESORT);
    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
    Console.ReadLine();                 
}
```

to

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine (record.RESORT);
    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

you will see all lines.

---

With your second code sample, the data you posted is missing a couple of fields and throws an exception. If you make `LAST_YEAR_01` and `SUB_GRP_1_ORDER` nullable it works for the data provided. i.e. change the lines to

```
public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
```

Also note that you specified to skip the last 2 lines, so I manually added 2 dummy lines to the end of the file for my test.

I believe it may have been appearing to start halfway through the file as it was discarding the invalid lines (though I'm not sure why you weren't getting an exception).

If you still have issues after making these changes, please post the full data file in the question formatted as code (it gets a bit messed up posted as a comment and needs manual tweaking).